# Cannot type in JavaFx TextField once its TextProperty is binding is set

Tags: java, javafx

To test the property binding in Javafx, I have created two `TextField` as the following:

```
public class BindingTest extends Application {

  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    TextField text1 = new TextField();
    TextField text2 = new TextField();

//      text1.textProperty().bindBidirectional(text2.textProperty());
    text1.textProperty().bind(text2.textProperty());

    VBox root = new VBox(text1, text2);

    stage.setTitle("Binding Test");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
    stage.show();

  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

When I use bidirectional binding, I can type in both text fields, and the text property binding works perfectly. But when I use unidirectional binding, text field 1 does update its content when I type in text field 2, but I cannot type in text field 1 anymore.

Is it normal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to use a bi-directional binding.

If you use an uni-directional binding you say that the value in text1 has to be the same as the value in text2 which would not be the case if you could type.